# Paypal MassPay API Note and Memo field

Tags: paypal, masspay

While using upload CSV file option to MassPay, we can add "Note" and "Memo" to each transaction which can be used later.
I want to add same "Note" and "Memo" fields in Paypal transactions sent using MassPay API. But I am unable to find any field in the MassPay API documentation.
How can I populate these fields?

Answer (score 0):

use the parameter 'L_NOTEn' to add note or memo
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/

PayPal Merchant SDK
https://github.com/paypal?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=merchant&type=&language=

Comment: Parameter 'LNOTEn' is used to add note for recipient, "Custom note for each recipient." But the Note and Memo I want to add is displayed on sender's account.